# Purpose of rheostat in measuring resistance

Tags: resistance, rheostat

I was given task to measure the resistance of different length of same conductor to find the relationship between length and resistance. The circuit diagram is something like this:

[image: circuit diagram to measure resistance with ammeter and voltmeter]

The resistance,R is replace with different length of the conductor  thorough the experiment. The rheostat is adjusted so that the ammeter reading is always the same for the different wire length.

My question is why the rheostat is needed in this experiment to adjusted the current. Isn't that we can get the resistance by dividing the voltmeter reading to ammeter reading, even without the rheostat?

Answer (score 3):

The rheostat is so that you can adjust the current down, to be 'convenient'. Maybe you might want to get an exact reading on one of the meters. Perhaps you want to measure a very small values of resistance, when without the rheostat the current would be too large for the cell to deliver.

Answer (score 2):

For low values of R, you might need some more resistance in series to keep you voltage source happy. Apart from that, with ideal conponents your theory that it isn't needed is sound.